# Data Protection keys collection is intermittently modified causing 401 errors

Tags: authentication, .net-5, azure-keyvault

I have a two sites that share an authentication cookie:

- Main site that generates auth cookie
- Chat site that hosts a SignalR Hub.

The Main site's cookie is sent through and used to authenticate SignalR negotiation requests.

I recently deployed some large scale changes moving from ASP.NET Framework to .NET5. Part of this change meant using the new Data Protection keys so the auth ticket on both apps could be decrypted (previously, the ASP.NET Framework version just needed the machine keys on both apps to match, which could be set in web.config).

Here's what the Data Protection code looks like, used in both the Main and Chat sites:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCustomDataProtection(_configuration);
    ...
}

public static IServiceCollection AddCustomDataProtection(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var siteSettings = configuration
        .GetSection(SiteSettings.SectionName)
        .Get<SiteSettings>();

    var dataProtection = services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName(siteSettings.SiteName);

    var dataProtectionSettings = configuration
        .GetSection(DataProtectionSettings.SectionName)
        .Get<DataProtectionSettings>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataProtectionSettings.KeyVaultIdentifier))
    {
        dataProtection
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(
                configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageConnectionString"),
                dataProtectionSettings.KeyStoreContainerName,
                dataProtectionSettings.KeyStoreBlobName)
            .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(
                new Uri(dataProtectionSettings.KeyVaultIdentifier),
                new DefaultAzureCredential());
    }

    return services;
}
```

Since this was deployed, we've had some strange issues whereby the Data Protection keys blob stored in Azure Storage is modified throughout the day. It doesn't look like there's any rhyme or reason behind when this happens.

From my understanding, the Data Protection keys are by default refresh every 90 days or so, however this is happening 1-2 times a day. The code in the apps never interact with the Key Vault keys nor the Data Protection key blob directly (only via the code posted below) and I have added logs that show the correct settings *are* being passed through to the Data Protection extension methods.

On the other hand, I have been having intermittent issues where when the Main site sends an negotiate request to the Chat site, it receives a 401 error, indicating that the the cookie/auth ticket was invalid or otherwise couldn't be decrypted. I can reproduce this when the key is modified by restarting the Main site, logging out and then logging in again. I think these two problems are related.

My stab-in-the-dark explanation of this behaviour would be that perhaps the Main site is correctly picking up a change in the Data Protection keys, however the Chat site does not. The Chat site cannot then decrypt an auth ticket that was encrypted using a key it doesn't have access to. Restarting the Chat site fixes the issue, presumably because the Data Protection keys are reloaded at startup.

So I have two main concerns:

1. why is the Data Protection key blob being modified?
2. why is the Chat site not picking up the new keys if indeed new keys are being added to the collection of Data Protection keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that both the Main and Chat sites stored the data protection keys **in the same blob** in Azure Storage. This caused the strange behaviour I was witnessing with the blob being modified, and in turn, the application errors I was experiencing.

I figured storing the keys in the same location would be fine due to my reading of the documentation at the time relating to the SetApplicationName() method causing the keys to be isolated from one another. Unfortunately that isolation did not extend to the actual physical data protection keys rather, just the payload stored inside of them. [The documentation surrounding app isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#per-application-isolation) has since been updated and is now far more detailed.